# Django makemigrations continues to detect removing of translated fields

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-modeltranslation

I'm using django 1.10 and django-modeltranslation.
I've removed registrations of translated fields for my models and applied sync_translation_fields management command.

But now, everytime I run makemigrations, django produce migrations to remove fields and, although I can fake these, running tests gives errors because migrations try to remove those non existing fields.

How to clean up this situation?